# how to create a existing file in java

Tags: java, file, io

I am asking of there's a way how I could put like a program or a bat file or any file that has stuff written in it and them when he clicks on a button it will create that file that i have put into my project on to the users desktop is there a way?

```
File test = new File("C:/Users/"
                      + System.getProperty("user.name")
                      + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/mods/welcome.txt");
try { test.createNewFile(); } 
catch (IOException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }
```

this doesnt work.

Comment: what does not work? what are you expecting to happen in your code which is not happening? are you getting any errors?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok i found out how i just downloaded the files from a server that i have "made"

Answer (score 1):

If the file you want to creating is already exist in the disk, then you can print a message like the "File already exists" -

```
     try { 
          File file = new File("c:\\some\location\file_name.txt");

          if (file.createNewFile()){
            System.out.println("File is created!");
          }else{
            System.out.println("File already exists.");
          }

    }catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to just put a file on an other computer you will need to be granted permission in some way to do that (otherwise anyone could just infect any networked computer with any content they desired).  There are several ways you could gain access to an other computer (look into virtual private network and mapped network drive).  The most common way of delivering files to another computer is to set up a web site where the user can request the file to be downloaded to their machine by clicking on a link. You could also write a client program that used an http get to allow the client user to request content be downloaded to a specific place on their machine.